# WooCommerce как сделать выбор количества товаров в модальном окне?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Создал модальное окно с помощью плагина.
Вот так это выглядит на практике:

[image]

Хотелось бы что-бы прям в этом окне, можно было бы выбрать количество товаров в корзину. Красным отметил примерную зону.

Сам плагин не даёт такое сделать, но может быть куда-то код можно вставить? Я так-то само поле для ввода смогу сделать, но мне бы примерно указать как сделать такое.